# Django REST Framework image upload

Tags: django, image-upload, django-rest-framework

I have model Product:

```
def productFile(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join( ['products', str(instance.id), filename] )

class Product(models.Model):
    ...

    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=productFile,
        max_length=254, blank=True, null=True
    )
    ...
```

Then I have serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            ...
            'image',
            ...
        )
```

And then I have views:

```
class ProductViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

How I can upload image with Postman? What is the best practices to upload image to model? Thank you.

Comment: Remove the paranthesis, `serializer_class = ProductSerializer`.. If you are using `ModelViewSet`, then you don't need to write anything more... `ViewSet` would handle pretty much everything for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks, and how can I upload image with postman, or some Ajax request?

Comment: When I use that in my model, I get a ValueError("Cannot serialize function: lambda")

Comment: @Rony Azrak, I'he just updated the question with a solution that works. use method `productFile `

Comment: Can you send me your code to post data in model with image file I'm wondering for it..my code show me bad request 400 http://....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can create separate endpoint for uploading images, it would be like that:

```
class ProductViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def upload_docs(request):
        try:
            file = request.data['file']
        except KeyError:
            raise ParseError('Request has no resource file attached')
        product = Product.objects.create(image=file, ....)
```

you can go around that solution

-- update:
this's how to upload from postman
[image]

Comment: you can upload using postman by select `form-data` on body and select type to file and click on choose file, write `file` on key field  
see the update above.

Comment: Thank you! Can I have url with method "PUT" like `/api/products/33/upload_docs` ?

Comment: yes you can of course but I didn't check if you can upload with `PUT` method or not

Comment: hm, I'm, just tried your solution, but I got error `{"detail":"Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter."}` . Do you know how can I "turn off" this requirement? Once more Thank you! :)

Comment: `filename` is required to upload, I think it's issue in postman, if you try any frontend code to test this api it's easy to set filename

Comment: problem was with parser, I used FileUploadParser instead of MultiPartParser :) Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

I lately start Django and have same problem for upload image.

All steps that i done

1. Install Pillow for using ImageField

   ```
   pip install Pillow
   ```
2. In `Settings.py` add these lines

   ```
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # 'http://myhost:port/media/'
   ```
3. Use ImageField in model.py (create `nameFile` function for create folder and name of file)

   ```
   def upload_to(instance, filename):
       return '/'.join(['images', str(instance.name), filename])

   class UploadImageTest(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
   ```
4. serializer.py

   ```
   class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = UploadImageTest
           fields = ('name', 'image')
   ```
5. views.py

   ```
   class ImageViewSet(ListAPIView):
       queryset = UploadImageTest.objects.all()
       serializer_class = ImageSerializer

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           file = request.data['file']
           image = UploadImageTest.objects.create(image=file)
           return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': "Uploaded"}), status=200)
   ```
6. urls.py: add this line

   ```
   path('upload/', views.ImageViewSet.as_view(), name='upload'),
   ```
7. admin.py: add this line (for check in admin)

   ```
   admin.site.register(UploadImageTest)
   ```
8. in terminal

   ```
   python manage.py makemigrations
   python manage.py migrate
   ```

Comment: Have you tried to use `MultiPartParser ` in views?

Also I would recommend you to make new endpoint to 'upload_image' in `ImageViewSet`

Comment: can you tell how to update this in request.

Answer (score 4):

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ImageUpload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    images = models.ImageField('images')
```

> serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ImageUpload

class ImageUploadSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ImageUpload
        fields= (
            'title',
            'images'
        )
```

> views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import ImageUpload
from .serializers import ImageUploadSerializer

class ImageUploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ImageUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageUploadSerializer
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'imageupload', views.ImageUploadViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('imageupload', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: this is best way to do it. in my thinking. thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### this worked for me

```py
class UserAvatarUpload(ListAPIView):
    
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data['username']
        file = request.data['image']
        user = MyModel.objects.get(username=username)
        user.image = file
        user.save()
        return Response("Image updated!", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```