# ImageField set to null after passing through serializer for update profile | DRF | Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to update user's profile image. User's profile is being automatically created on the created of the user. At that time a default avatar is set.

I am using Token Authentication

```
Authorization : Token a877b60afeb45e1ada12e10ecf4d0c8065b15569
```

But when trying to update my

**request.data**

```
<QueryDict: {'date_of_birth': ['1990-05-02'], 'profile_image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image_5854.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

**serilizer.data**

```
{'profile_image': None, 'date_of_birth': '1990-05-02'}
```

**Models.py**

```
@deconstructible

class UploadToPathAndRename(object):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.sub_path = path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        # get filename
        if instance.pk:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
        else:
            # set filename as random string
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        # return the whole path to the file
        return os.path.join(self.sub_path, filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=UploadToPathAndRename(os.path.join('images/avatar/')),
                                      default='images/avatar/default.jpg')
    participated = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    won = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    runner_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ProfilePUTSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    profile_image = ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('profile_image', 'date_of_birth',)
```

**Views.py**

```
class ProfilePUTAPIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        print(request.content_type)
        print(request.stream)
        serializer = ProfilePUTSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.pk)
            user.__dict__.update(serializer.data)
            user.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Please suggest what to do?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this `serializer.data['profile_image'] = request.data['profile_image']` ? Did you tried using request.FILES ?

Comment: Did you checked this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564130/django-rest-framework-image-upload

Comment: @Umair I was just trying to see if this works ;). Removed it.

Comment: Ah! ok
Did you checked those 2 links and tried those ?

Comment: What does `serializer.validated_data` show?

Comment: @WillKeeling `serializer.initial_data` and `serializer.validated_data` both show `profile_image` as the  `InMemoryUploadedFile` but `serializer.data` shows `profile_image` as `None`. Do you have an idea as to why that is?

Comment: I think the `InMemoryUploadedFile` is created when the validators are run and so won't show up in `request.data`. You'd have to have a close look at the source to be sure.

Comment: Yes, Its is same as mentioned by 'user9867933'.

Comment: @Umair Yes I tried but no help.