# Django REST Framework - empty request body

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've just started messing around with Django REST today and wanted to create a PUT endpoint for a photo upload. The image is then to be saved to a local folder. I'm using the MultiPartParser but request.data and request.FILES are both empty? Anyone know how why that might be?

Views.py:

```
class ImageUploadView(APIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        print(request.FILES)
        return Response(status=204)
```

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my postman test
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ZaB.png)

Comment: try to put some value in POSTMAN while making PUT request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564130/django-rest-framework-image-upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django REST Framework image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564130/django-rest-framework-image-upload)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a key to the file value in the postman form fixed it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MApRr.png)