# Send image via post request to ImageField

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with API for an ImageField. I need to send image fetched via post method on the template and send it via post request to the API created. The image fetched has a type `InMemoryUploadedFile`, if I try to send it directly, I get 406 because of failed serializer validation. So I tried making a PIL object out of it and tried sending. I checked the JS counterpart of the code and it just takes the file from the input field and sends it directly to the same field and it works.

Is there a way I can just send an image file object via post request to fail serializer validation.

```
category_thumbnail = request.FILES.get('category_thumbnail')

category_thumbnail = Image.open(category_thumbnail)
data = {
   'category_thumbnail': category_thumbnail
}
```

This would give me 406.

I also tried converting image string to a base64 byte object.

```
category_thumbnail = request.FILES.get('category_thumbnail')

category_thumbnail = Image.open(category_thumbnail)

with io.BytesIO() as output:
   category_thumbnail.save(output, format="GIF")
   contents = output.getvalue()

category_thumbnail = base64.b64decode(contents)
data = {
   'category_thumbnail': category_thumbnail
}
```

but this would give me 406 too.

I wonder if there's a way I can just send the image file object taken from `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

Also tried

```
category_thumbnail = request.FILES.get('category_thumbnail').file
```

Comment: What is the server expecting for the field 'category_tumbnail'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564130/django-rest-framework-image-upload ?

Comment: @AkashRudra it is an ImageField and in the API it's just validating through the serializer. So an image type object.

Comment: @JPG that's an issue he's facing on the API side. My problem is on the view side. I need to send image as a parameter and not receive one.

Answer (score 0):

if the code is in API, you should use `request.data` instead of `request.FILES`
if the code is in normal html view, like a form. then it should be using an `HTML form` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or `FormData` generated by javascripts.

And in views:

```
obj.category_thumbnail = request.FILES['category_thumbnail']
```

it should be used directly with rest_framework, no matter it is `InMemoryUploadedFile` or `UploadedFile`.

**If, for some reason, you are using `serializer` rather than `form` in `view`.
Then the view should be derived from `APIView` if class based. Or use `@api_view` decorator to function based view.**

Comment: Your soution  again is on the API side. The API shows accepted with 200 when sending files with postman or JS. I need to send *Image* type file via json to the API created from my view.

Comment: @coder you say it is not about API side, then what do you mean `to API created from my view`? What does the `view` do? Mentioned that If it is a django standard view, then the standard way is to use form. Or it shall be an APIView or @api_view.

Comment: @coder Your codes in the post does not throw exceptions at all. The Exception shall be when you try to validate and save the image with the `serializer` right?

Comment: my bad. The API is created and hosted on a different server. What I'm doing is independent of that server. I'm hosting this code on different machine and sending post request to the API which is created on a different server. Let's just consider this as a python problem.

Comment: Maybe I am totally missed... Is your question "How to send submitted image using python?"