# How to upload photos to a file in my computer using Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, photo

I created a photo model, serializer and view, Users Can upload photos to my website. I learned that the best solution to do it is to upload the photo on the computer and the path on data base. But how Can i upload the photo to my computer via my website or my api ?

Modèles.py

```
ken authentification. So for adding an Announcement the user must be authenticated.

Models.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name='email', 
              unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

class Announcement(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     photo = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, blank=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     content_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Serializers.py

```
class AnnouncementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=True)
    parameters = ParameterSerializer(many=True, 
       required=False)
    photo = PhotoSerializer(many=True, 
        required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'author', 
                         'parameters', 'photo']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo = PhotoSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email','photo', ]

class ParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parameter
        fields = '__all__'
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views.py

```
class AnnouncementCreate(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = models.Announcement.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnnouncementSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ImageField` in your model. Then when you upload image to your url, django saves it in a dir which you should set in `MEDIA_ROOT` section in `settings.py`:

First install `pillow` for using `ImageField`:

```
pip3 install pillow
```

After that, add this field as photo to your model:

```py
...
photo = models.ImageField(...)
...
```

This can be helpful : [Django REST Framework image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564130/django-rest-framework-image-upload)

Comment: But how to save the path in thé path field ?

Comment: There is no need to path field any more @Zero0

Comment: it Worked Thanks a lot , but why name filed is even needed ? it creates a new foelder everytime the name field is entered